# Is there a C# code to make equivalent to "aws s3 ls [my_bucket]"?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I need list all files that I have in my cloud. I know that I can do it with aws-cli using the code "aws s3 ls [my bucket]".
But, how can I make the same thing using C# code?

I have saw the AWS documentation, but the only thing that I find is to do download of the files, is not what I want.

Some links that I used:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RetrievingObjectUsingNetSDK.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HLuploadFileDotNet.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for the .Net SDK can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/).

In general, you are looking for an operation called ListObjects of the S3 service ([HTTP API link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/v2-RESTBucketGET.html)).  This is implemented in the .Net SDK under the `Amazon.S3` namespace in a class called `AmazonS3Client` with a method [`ListObjectsResponse ListObjects(ListObjectsRequest)`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/S3/MS3ListObjectsListObjectsRequest.html).

Here is the example of its use from the last link:

```
// Create a client
AmazonS3Client client = new AmazonS3Client();

// List all objects
ListObjectsRequest listRequest = new ListObjectsRequest
{
    BucketName = "SampleBucket",
};

ListObjectsResponse listResponse;
do
{
    // Get a list of objects
    listResponse = client.ListObjects(listRequest);
    foreach (S3Object obj in listResponse.S3Objects)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Object - " + obj.Key);
        Console.WriteLine(" Size - " + obj.Size);
        Console.WriteLine(" LastModified - " + obj.LastModified);
        Console.WriteLine(" Storage class - " + obj.StorageClass);
    }

    // Set the marker property
    listRequest.Marker = listResponse.NextMarker;
} while (listResponse.IsTruncated);
```